# len() function does not work for me in iPython Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Here is a short example.

```
    lister = [1,3,5]
    # why doesn't next line work?
    lenl = len(lister)
    # the following line works 
    ll = lister.__len__() 
    print ll
```

Here is the output when I run it:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
        1 lister = [1,3,5]
        2 # why doesn't next line work?
  ----> 3 lenl = len(lister)
        4 # the following line works
        5 ll = lister.**len**()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

If the line

```
lenl = len(lister)
```

gives the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

then that's telling you that `len` is an `int`, not a function.  You must have rebound the name `len` to a specific integer.  For example:

```
>>> lister = [1,3,5]
>>> len(lister)
3
>>> len = len(lister)
>>> len
3
>>> len(lister)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-eeb2834390f6>", line 1, in <module>
    len(lister)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

You can recover the standard binding by typing `del len`:

```
>>> del len
>>> len(lister)
3
```

Comment: Thanks that is what happened.